# Change nested property of an Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Having an object of this form:

```
const myObj = {
    'firstA': {
       'secondC': [1,2,3],
       'secondD': [4,5,6],
    },
    'firstB':{
       'secondE': [0,0,0],
       'secondF': [1,1,1],
  },
}
```

I'm accessing one of its children's array, for example `secondC`.

In this case, the application uses `appValue = myObj.firstA.secondC`.

The values `secondC`, `secondD`, `secondE` and `secondF` are on a dropdown so the user can click on one of them and the application must reload with the new data.

Is there a way to get that value if it is not specified the "middle" node? (on dropdown there is no `firstA` or `firstB`)

Comment: wouldn't that be same as creating another myObj without the nesting ?

Comment: Your question is totaly unclear ? How does the values from your object get into a *dropdown* and what do you mean by the *dropdown* anyway ?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the "middle" value from an array?

Comment: can you post your attempt at the dropdown code or maybe an example of what the "sudo dropdown" would look like?? I am not certain exactly what you are asking here...

Comment: If you have a variable `let key="secondC"`, you can get the array by doing something like this: `Object.values(myObj).find(o => key in o)[key]`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to keep a track of the middle key also like

```
{
  "secondC":"fristA",
  "secondD":"fristA",
}
```

Then when the user selects from the dropdown you can lookup in the mapping and know the middle key. You can create this mapping once and use it as a cache instead if searching through everytime.

Here is the code to generate the mapping between subkeys and middle keys:

```js
const myObj = {
    'firstA': {
       'secondC': [1,2,3],
       'secondD': [4,5,6],
    },
    'firstB':{
       'secondE': [0,0,0],
       'secondF': [1,1,1],
  },
}

const mapping = Object.keys(myObj).reduce((acc,key)=>{
  const subKeys = Object.keys(myObj[key]);
  for(const subkey of subKeys){
   acc[subkey] = key
  }
  return acc
},{})

console.log(mapping)
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like `Object.entries` to iterate your object and find the key you are looking for:

```js
const myObj = {
    'firstA': {
       'secondC': [1,2,3],
       'secondD': [4,5,6],
    },
    'firstB':{
       'secondE': [0,0,0],
       'secondF': [1,1,1],
  },
}

// Let's say the user selected "secondE"
let key = "secondE";
// Now find it:
let [mid, midValue] = Object.entries(myObj).find(([mid, midValue]) => key in midValue);

console.log(mid, key, midValue[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your object into a flat one, and use it instead:

```js
const myObj = {
  'firstA': {
    'secondC': [1, 2, 3],
    'secondD': [4, 5, 6],
  },
  'firstB': {
    'secondE': [0, 0, 0],
    'secondF': [1, 1, 1],
  },
};

const $select = document.querySelector('select');
const $pre = document.querySelector('pre');

const options = Object.entries(myObj)
                      .reduce((res, [key, obj]) => ({...res, ...obj}), {});
  
Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
  const $option = document.createElement('option');
  $option.value = key;
  $option.innerText = key;
  $select.appendChild($option);
});

$select.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const key = e.target.value;
  const value = key ? JSON.stringify(options[key]) : '';
  $pre.innerHTML = value;
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option>-- Select a property --</option>
</select>
<pre></pre>
```